# Render custom formType option in twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.8

I have this problem in Symfony 2.8: I can't render a custom variable with my query passed to form option.

See the below code what i have tried :

This is my controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\FooAdminType', $res, array('attr' => array('fooOnes' => $Choices)));  
//when $choices is my dql query
```

This is my formType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {      
    $builder->add('bar', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Foo',
        'choices' => $options['attr']['FooOnes'],
        'required' => true,                    
        'property' => 'name',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label text-center'
         )
    ))
```

finally, my twig template

```
{% for foo in form.bar %}
    {{ form_widget(foo) }}
{% endfor %}
```

...Without the `for` block, the form is rendered. With the `for` block, I have this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 277.

PS: I have defined the `public function __toString()` in the entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing your code, the way you have set it up right now, you will be rendering a select element. Therefore, it doesn't make any sense for you to be looping through it.

You will need to set the attribute `expanded` to `true` in order for you to be able to use the `for` loop. This way, you will be rendering either radio buttons or checkboxes, depending on the multiple value.

For checkboxes:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {      
$builder
            ->add('bar', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Foo',
                'choices' => $options['attr']['FooOnes'],
                'required' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'property' => 'name',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label text-center'
                )
            ))
```

Comment: You rigth! 
    `code` 'expanded' => true `code`
but the error still here

Comment: You rigth! ` 'expanded' => true` render the widget, and `'multiple' => true` render as checkbox
but the error is not in for block. Is in the `{{ form_star(form) }}` and `{{ form_end(form) }}`...  I don't know why.

Comment: Do you mean you are still getting the same error? Can you show the code for your form_div_layout.html.twig especially line 277 where the error is, if it is the same error that is.

Comment: the form_div_layout.html.twig is an vendor file.
for pragmaticly cuestions, I delete {{ form_star(form) }} and {{ form_end(form) }} and I writeit "by hand". For my and for the time I (don't) have this is ok. Maybe later checkit what happend here